# ActiveRecord Query in another query, like "IN" with SQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

i would like write this query in Rails/Active Record

```
SELECT *  FROM messages WHERE (realtor_id,created_at) IN  ( SELECT realtor_id, MAX(created_at),message   FROM messages   WHERE `messages`.`user_id` = 8   GROUP BY realtor_id );
```

I tried some syntaxes but it doesnt work...
I think, the solution is near :

```
@discussions = Message.where(realtor_id: created_at: [Message.where(:user_id => current_user.id).select("realtor_id, MAX(created_at) as created_at").group("realtor_id").order("created_at ASC")])
```

Someone can help me ?

Thanks for advance,

F.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create sql query and pass in

```
query = "SELECT *  FROM messages WHERE (realtor_id,created_at) IN  ( SELECT realtor_id, MAX(created_at),message FROM messages WHERE `messages`.`user_id` = 8   GROUP BY realtor_id )"

@discussions = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query)
```